# Materialize swipeable tabs issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i making a code with materialize tab and had customised its tab indicatior as seen  in image [customised tab indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cBpe.jpg)

The concern is that the yellow tab indicator overlays the tab
I want that the text should come over the tab indicator

Following is css code of tab indicator, tab , and tab a, and tabs

```
        .tabs {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #262626;
  border-radius:50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tabs .tab {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width:calc(80%/2);
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tabs .tab a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration:none;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family:Enviro;
  -webkit-transition: color .28s ease, background-color .28s ease;
  transition: color .28s ease, background-color .28s ease;
}

.tabs .indicator {
  position:absolute;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius:50px;
  background-color: #f5d247;
  will-change: left, right;
}
```

```
            <div id="swipe-1" class="col s12 ">First tab content</div>
            <div id="swipe-2" class="col s12 ">Second tab content</div>
            
            <ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#swipe-1">REGISTER</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#swipe-2">LOGIN</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Please help me to be able bring the text over the yellow tab indicator . The html code for tab is same

Comment: Please post your HTML code

Comment: Added the html code

Comment: Css code is messed up. Please fix it. The first css class has no name. It starts with a property

Comment: Sorry i didn't reviewed it , it is fixed now